# Inner Loop Behavior After Element Deletion

Tags: python, loops

I have a large list of elements which contain other lists and dictionary values. The basic structure is:

```
for i in outer:
    for j in range(len(inner)-1,-1,-1):
        if j:
            del outer[i]
```

So the presence of data in a nested structure dictates whether we retain that entire element in the outer list. Deleting the elements creates an immediate shift in the outer list.

Would I need to explicitly continue the control logic or does this occur implicitly for me?

```
for i in outer:
    for j in range(len(inner)-1,-1,-1):
        if j:
            del outer[i]
            continue
```

I am currently using the former setup which appears to be giving me my desired results while running tests. I guess I am simply trying to determine if the inner loop needlessly will run after the call to `del` or if Python is smart enough to know that the previous ith element has been removed and it is no longer necessary to continue iterating over its internals.

Comment: why don't you just `print(i)` and test for yourself?

Comment: `del outer[i]` doesn't do what you think it does. `i` is the element, not its index.

Comment: Did you mean something like `for i, inner in enumerate(outer):`?

Comment: @Yevhen Kuzmovych Not sure what you are referencing here.

Comment: @Barmar I am unfamiliar with the approach using enumerate, I'll take a look at it. And just to be clear, removing the element is exactly what I want to do. I'm not actually interested in the indexing at all, but when I delete the element the current `i` becomes the previous `i`, which is really why I had this question to begin with.

Comment: I understand that you want to delete the element. But `i` isn't the index of the element, it's a variable that holds the contents of the element. So there's no such thing as `outer[i]`.

Comment: You generally should not modify a list while you're iterating over it with `for var in list`. There are a number of SO questions that address this and show the proper workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Python is not "smart enough" to do what you are assuming. Some hard-coded `continue`s/`break`s are definitely needed if you do not want the inner loop to continue after the deletion.

In general, you should not delete elements of a container that you are looping over. It is not clear to me what exactly you are doing in your example code, but one example where it is allowed (though still frown upon) is to loop backwards over a list (is that what you are attempting?) and delete the current or later element.

As an aside, are you sure that you want to delete the `i`'th element of `outer`, when `i` is not an index but the actual `i`'th element itself?

Comment: Thanks for this, incorporating a continue into this was what I figured would be necessary. I try to avoid using continue/break where I can and usually in situations such as this there is probably a better way to more pythonically implement this logic.

In regards to not deleting elements of a container that I am looping over; this is also something I am aware of. Realistically making a copy and deleting elements out of it would be a better way to go. I can't find the exact reference any longer, but this code was partially a solution to another question, however it did not clarify this issue.